# Finding and replacing the time stamp data in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a mysql database with table description as

- Name
- data
- Time_stamp

time_stamp column is having value in date time data type like **'2013-08-12 12:12:34'**
Like this there are multiple records .

I want to replace the records where value is like **'2013-08-12 % '** to **'2013-08-13 %'**.
I dont want to change the **hh:mm:ss** values in time_stamp.

How can i do this .

Comment: what type is `time_stamp`? `text` or `timestamp`?

Comment: you can try using dateADD 24 hours. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: time_stamp is of datetime data type .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can try following query,

```
UPDATE tablename SET time_stamp = concat('2011-08-13 ', time(time_stamp))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work fast if there is an index on `time_stamp` column:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET time_stamp = time_stamp + INTERVAL 1 DAY
WHERE time_stamp >= '2013-08-12'
  AND time_stamp <  '2013-08-13'
```